# CakePHP 2.x retriving data with i18n in a loop

Tags: loops, cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-2.1

I'm looping trough Features (belongTo FeatureType) and find() FeatureType.name for each Feature.feature_type_id.
I'm getting first record correct (with i18n translation) but in all the rest the i18n translation is not in place, but given as separate record.

What I am doing wrong?

this is the debug of my result table:

```
array(
    'FeatureType' => array(
        'id' => '28',
        'name' => 'kolor suwaka',
        'comment' => 'kolor suwaka etui notebook',
        'locale' => 'pol'
    )
)

array(
    'FeatureType' => array(
        'id' => '7',
        'name' => '',
        'comment' => '',
        'locale' => 'pol'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'FeatureType__i18n_name' => 'kolor materiału',
        'FeatureType__i18n_comment' => 'gra w klasy'
    )
)

array(
    'FeatureType' => array(
        'id' => '11',
        'name' => '',
        'comment' => '',
        'locale' => 'pol'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'FeatureType__i18n_name' => 'kolor',
        'FeatureType__i18n_comment' => 'kółko i krzyżyk (jasnoszare i ciemnoszare)'
    )
)

array(
    'FeatureType' => array(
        'id' => '27',
        'name' => '',
        'comment' => '',
        'locale' => 'pol'
    ),
    (int) 0 => array(
        'FeatureType__i18n_name' => 'obwód głowy',
        'FeatureType__i18n_comment' => 'rozmiar kapelusza czarownicy'
    )
)
```

This is the code:

```
$features_str = "";
if (!empty($product['Features'])) {
    foreach ($product['Features'] as $featureIndex => $feature) {
        $featureTypeModel = new FeatureType();
        $feature_type = $featureTypeModel->find("first", array("conditions" => array("FeatureType.id" => $feature['feature_type_id'])));
        if (strlen($features_str) > 0) $features_str .= ", ";
        $features_str .= $feature_type['FeatureType']['name'] . ': ' . $feature['name'];
        unset($featureTypeModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code generating your output in the question.

Comment: I added the code - it is in another model - Product.

Comment: `$featureTypeModel = new FeatureType();`, and in a loop, that's a pretty bad habit you've got there, and that's probably the cause - use the class registry _once_ `$model = ClassRegistry::get('FeatureType');` and call find on the same instance. It's not clear why you'd do what you're doing since the code snippet is so small (i.e. you should post _your model code_, not a few lines of one method).

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I'll keep in mind what you wrote.